# Azure Websites and Event Logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, eventlog-source

I've an ASP.NET application I'm trying to migrate to an Azure website (shared).
In its current form this uses the Event Log to record exceptions.

On Azure websites I can't write to the Event Log so I get an exception trying to record the exception.

What is the recommended way of logging under Azure websites?  How can I detect that I'm running under a website and not on my own machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Azure storage table?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are not creating a new event source, you should be able to write to the event logs using same code. In azure app service, the event logs are available in the form of eventlog.xml.

You can read more about the event logs @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2014/09/24/azure-website-siteextension-to-view-eventlogs/